# Class not found in blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

This is my alert.blade.php file

```html
@if ($errors->any())
    <div>
        <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li style="color: red">{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

@if (Session::has('error'))
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li style="color: red">{{ Session::get('error') }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

@if (Session::has('success'))
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li style="color: green">{{ Session::get('success') }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

When run code the brower: Class "Session" not found. But yesterday it still work, today I clone code again but this error was show. I dont remember how to solve this. Please help

[image: login.blade.php]

And dashboard met same kind of error

```html
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <a href="/products/view/{{ $product->id }}" class="m-4">
        <div class="box-border h-{{ $h_box }} w-{{ $w_box }} p-4 border-4 justify-center rounded-md">
            <div class="box-border h-{{ $image_size }} w-{{ $image_size }} border-1 mx-auto">
                <img class="object-cover w-full h-full" src="{{ $product->thumb }}">
            </div>
            <div class="box-border h-16 w-{{ $image_size }} border-1 truncate mx-auto">
                <h2 class="mt-1 font-medium leading-tight text-base mb-2">{{ /Str::title($product->name) }}
                </h2>
                @if ($product->price > $product->sale_price)
                    <div class="inline-block">
                        <h2 class="font-medium leading-tight text-base mt-0 mb-2 text-red-500">
                            <p class="line-through inline">{{ /Str::title($product->price) }}$</p> -> <p
                                class="inline">{{ /Str::title($product->sale_price) }}$</p>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                @else
                    <h2 class="font-medium leading-tight text-base mt-0 mb-2 text-red-500">
                        {{ /Str::title($product->price) }}$
                    </h2>
                @endif

            </div>
            <div class="box-border h-16 w-{{ $image_size }} border-1 truncate mx-auto">
                <h2 class="mt-1 text-left leading-tight text-base mb-2">0 star | 0 sale
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
@endforeach
```

[image: category.blade.php in (dashboard)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel's session helper function like this

```
@if (session()->has('error'))
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li style="color: red">{{ session()->get('error') }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

@if (session()->has('success'))
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li style="color: green">{{ session()->get('success') }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

or you can also do this

```
@if (Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::has('error'))
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li style="color: red">{{ Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get('error') }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

@if (Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::has('success'))
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li style="color: green">{{ Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get('success') }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

And for the `Str` error you can do the same

```
{{ Illuminate\Support\Str::title($product->name) }}
{{ Illuminate\Support\Str::title($product->price) }}
// and so on....
```

Comment: it still not work

Comment: What's not working? Did you copied the code from the edited answer?

Comment: way 2 not work, I mean

Comment: Define "not work".. Are you receiving error or what? If "way 2" is not working, then try "way 1".

Comment: beacause, I want to use some other class like Arr, Str more. How way 1 can replace them

Comment: way 1 have same error with my code

Comment: With "\" before them. `\Arr::`, `\Str::`. But this is not mentioned in your question? I don't see Arr or Str in you question.

Comment: Please show the full error.

Comment: I added some picture and other blade use Str in the question

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\Illuminate\Support\Str::
\Illuminate\Support\Arr::
```

et cetera